# Field as Block column not showing

Tags: entities, blocks, plugins

I installed the Field as Block plugin without problems, but when I go to Structure > Content Types > Basic Page > Manage Display, I still don't see the "Display as block" checkbox.

I tried googling but did not find anything else that what was written on the [plugin page](https://www.drupal.org/project/fieldblock). What am I doing wrong? This plugin would really help me.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, I found a [post by nicholasThompson](https://www.drupal.org/node/2613112) who was having the same problem and found out the solution:

> Ahh you have to place the "Content field" block and configure it!

This solved my issue.